# assignment from incompatible pointer type/deref pointer to incomplete type

Tags: c, pointers, struct, reference, dereference

I have this binary tree where each struct, lets call them A has a pointer of another struct type, lets call them B, pointing to another struct type B and so forth(forming a linkedlist of struct type B).

Picture:

```
(A)
 /\
 (A)->(B)->(B)->(B)->||
```

The problem, i'm not sure. I am receiving an error that says:

```
AddRemove.c: In function ‘AddRemove’:
AddRemove.c:21: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type
AddRemove.c:22: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
AddRemove.c:23: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
AddRemove.c:24: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
AddRemove.c:26: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
```

The code:

```
struct A{
//other variables
struct A *left,*right;
struct B *queue;         
}*rootT;

struct B{
//other variables
struct B *next;
};

void AddRemove(struct A *aNode, struct B *bNode){
/*aNode is the memory location of the struct node (A) in the picture and bNode is
 a struct node that we want to add to the linkedlist.*/
struct B *Bptr; //Used to go through the linkedlist of struct type B
if(aNode->queue==NULL){ /*If the pointer of node (A) is null then we have the
pointer point to bNode, the node that we wanted to add.*/
    aNode->queue=bNode;
    bNode->next=NULL;
}
else{
    Bptr=aNode->queue; /*Otherwise have the temp pointer point to what
 node (A)'s pointer points to, which should be the first struct type (B)*/
    while(Bptr->next!=NULL){ /*Keep pointing to the next struct of type B until 
we hit the end*/
        Bptr=Bptr->next;
    }
    Bptr->next=bNode;
}
}
```

Comment: Add declaration: `struct B;` before definition of `struct A`

Comment: That did not change the errors i was receiving. I should mention these struct declaration are in a seperate .h file.

Comment: Are you including the header in this source code?  If not, you need to do so. The compiler won't be able to divine the types if you don't include them in the translation unit.

Comment: Yes i had it included, that is not the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Missing semicolon:

```
struct B{
    //other variables
    struct B *next;
};
 ^
```

Also, since you're using incomplete types inside the structure definitions, you should use `typedef`:

```
typedef struct A A;
typedef struct B B;

struct A {
    //other variables
    A *left,*right;
    B *queue;         
} *rootT;

struct B {
    //other variables
    B *next;
};
```

Comment: The compiler would be giving different errors if the semicolon was missing. It is perfectly permissible to use the `struct A` and `struct B` in pointers as originally written; there is no compulsion to use the `typedef`s you show. They are a good idea, though the Linux kernel does not use them (so not everyone agrees). However, you need to be clear about the difference between 'must be changed' and 'could/should be changed'. You do say 'should', but you don't really explain.

Comment: Maybe I'm barking up the wrong tree.  I thought it was required when you referenced one from the other, but maybe that's only when it's mutual cross-referencing.  I expect you're right about the header not being included.

Comment: If the `struct X` references are at file scope (not inside a function; not inside a function prototype), then basically you can mention `struct X` anywhere and it indicates that there is a structure type `struct X` and you can use it to define pointers to that type without any further detail. To define actual variables of the type `struct X`, the full type must be provided. Both `typedef` names and structure tags are scoped. _[...continued...]_

Comment: _[...continuation...]_ If you have a pair of mutually recursive structure types defined inside a function, then you write `struct X; struct Y { ...; struct X *xp; }; struct X { ...; struct Y *yp; }` to make sure that `xp` points to the `struct X` that follows rather than some other `struct X` that was previously defined at file scope. You don't need a `typedef` while you use `struct X`, but you do if you want to write: `typedef struct X X; typedef struct Y Y; struct X { ...; Y *yp; }; struct Y { ...; X *xp; };`.

Comment: I actually had the ; in my code, i just omitted it on stackoverflow. Anyways anyone has any idea? I had the header included as well.